# Auto Suggest PHP Code Like Google Search

Tags: php, search, autosuggest, keyword

I need a powerful search code for my product databse

In That I need to search keywords that present in product title and description

when we type a word it should list the word and next words following that word in the sentence.

Can Anybody help with the below code

```
$sql="SELECT REPEAT (pr_name,1) AS names, REPEAT (pr_description, 1) AS pdes, REPEAT ('pr',1) AS lity FROM products WHERE pr_name like '%".$searchq."%' OR pr_description like '%".$searchq."%'".$qrtxt1." UNION SELECT REPEAT (sr_title, 1) AS names, REPEAT (sr_description, 1) AS pdes, REPEAT ('ser',1) AS lity FROM services WHERE sr_title like '%".$searchq."%' OR sr_description like '%".$searchq."%'".$qrtxt2." ORDER BY names LIMIT 10";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
echo "<ul class='livelist'>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
 $restext1='';
 $restext2='';
 $restext1= magicWords($searchq, $row['names']);
 $restext2= magicWords($searchq, $row['pdes']);

 if(!empty($restext1))
 {
    $wrappedtext1=wordwrap($restext1);
    echo "<li id=".$row['lity']." onclick='clearlist(this.innerHTML,this.id)'>".substr($wrappedtext1, 0, strpos($wrappedtext1, "\n"))."<li>";


 }
 if(!empty($restext2))
 {
    $wrappedtext2=wordwrap($restext2);
    echo "<li id=".$row['lity']." onclick='clearlist(this.innerHTML,this.id)'>".substr($wrappedtext2, 0, strpos($wrappedtext2, "\n"))."<li>";


 }

  }
echo "</ul>";
```

Comment: tip: You should take a look at jQuery AutoSuggest plugin (http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/autosuggest-jquery-plugin) or jQuery AutoComplete plugin (http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this tutorial, you can get an idea to implement Auto suggest option as you want. There Sample code and demo available. You can develop Auto suggest task using this.
http://coding.pressbin.com/19/Implementing-Google-auto-suggest-using-jQuery

Demo: http://www.pressbin.com/

Comment: Your post is very good,,, thanks .I need the keyword search facility ie, if the word is present in the description the sentence starting from that word need to display; anyway thanks

Comment: @Sumesh Now try the updated links.But thats developed with PHP Jquery... They used Jquery Autocomplete plugin.